# how to create an on_press function for buttons in a loop in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying create on_press buttons in a loop, i have used the bind feature with it but it is giving an assertionerror of "None is not callable" despite the function having a value to run it. here is the code

```
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        objff = mm.Show()
        objf = mm.Storenote()
        objf.tif(mm.DB.hod)
    for i in range(len(mm.Storenote.ht)):
        self.b = Button(text=(mm.Storenote.ht[i]), font_size = "25sp")
        #self.b.background_normal = ""
        #self.b.size= (100, 50)
        #self.b.size_hint_y = None
        self.b.background_color = 0,0,1,1
        self.b.ids =  {"id":mm.Storenote.nid[i]}
        #self.l.append(self.b)
        #self.ds.append(self.b.ids.id)
        self.b.bind(on_press=(self.clickk()))
        self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.b)

        #self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.l[i])
def clickk(self):
    objff = mm.Show()
    objff.getter(self.b.ids.id)
    self.manager.current = "Readpage"
    self.remove_widget(self.b)
```

and when i tried try and except for the on_press path, runs the code automatically and moves the the "Readpage" without me pressing anything. what can i do? thanks

Comment: Change `self.b.bind(on_press=(self.clickk()))` to this **`self.b.bind(on_press=self.clickk)`**

Comment: I just tried this and I got a "TypeError: click take one positional argument but 2 were given when I clicked the button

Comment: That's expected as the event `on_press` passes the instance. That means you have to modify `clickk(self)` to `clickk(self, *args)` or atleast `clickk(self, instance)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It worked after I added the *args to the click function. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please one more thing. The buttons text are title of notes retrieved from a data base. I set the id  in the loop so that each button can have a unique id . how do I bind each button to its id  from the loop, so when I click each button, it can pick its unique Id. Right now the click function is only picking the last id  for all the buttons.

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing the main problem.

Comment: From my code above, the button I created using that loop is to display titles of notes saved in the database. I gave the buttons noteid as Id so I can use their id to query the database to retrieve both the title and the body of the note. But because the on-press function is outside of the loop, it is only picking the last button ids for the click function . What I want the click function to do is to pick each button Ids when the buttons are clicked. The self.b.ids.id  in the click function is suppose to use each button unique ids in the function. Everything is in the above code

Comment: *'Everything is in the above code'* no it can't be run. Take your time and check out [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).